# Flutter - Screen focus on a certain widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I need help to do the following: when I press List 1, the screen focuses on List 1; I need the same for the rest of the options

[image]

This is the code for the example:
[code](https://gist.github.com/cristianfb1989/d3d62d83e01058e9f89f6158d9177feb)

This behavior already exists in web pages but I haven't found this same behavior at the mobile app level. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by focus? You want to show List selected at the top of the screen?

Comment: Not in top, but, for example, I press the option "List 2", which in the following screen, focuses on list 2

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Like this
https://i.imgur.com/HbESSzw.gifv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small code snippet of something similar which might help you achieve you desired results.

By clicking the fab icon it will scroll down to item 35 within the ListView.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  final _cardHeight = 200.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        onPressed: () => _animateToIndex(35),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (_, i) => Container(
          height: _cardHeight,
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Scroll Item $i", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0),),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _animateToIndex(index) {
    _scrollController.animateTo(_cardHeight * index,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have a scrollable `Widget` (like `ListView`, `SingleScrollableWidget`) instead of a `Column` in `ListSecondPage`.

Then add a `ScrollController` to it and `ListSecondPage` should receive which button was tapped. Based on that selection you can scroll to the desired location with the `ScrollController`

Comment: "Then add a ScrollController to it and ListSecondPage should receive which button was tapped."

How do I do this? I don't understand how to do this. Do you have an example to look at?